# How to set 4 images to linear layout acording to devices in android

Tags: android, imageview

I have 4 images within linearlayout that is created programmatically and i want to set textview on top of fourth image how to set??if u have piece of code please share with me??

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300, 1.0f);

public void path(ArrayList<Integer> integerImg) {
    // int width=mContext.getWgetWindowManager().getDefaultDispaly.getWidth();
    ImageView images;
    for (int i = 0; i < integerImg.size(); i++) {
        if (i < 4) {
            images = new ImageView(mContext);
            params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
            images.setLayoutParams(params);
            images.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            images.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.salon_profile_back);
            images.setImageResource(integerImg.get(i));
            linearImgGrid.addView(images);
        }
```

Comment: Could you please share your code with us and show us the part that does not work.

Comment: see above the code i want to display textview on top of 4th image???

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
TextView tv= new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("hallo hallo");
            tv.setId(5);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //add the 4th linear layout
            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(tv);
```

Comment: i didn't understand this??can u please edit my code with ur code and send me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of add an `ImageView` in the `LinearLayout`, you could create a `RelativeLayout` put inside an `ImageView` and a `TextView` and add `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`, as this:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsImage = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsText = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParamsText.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);


    for (int i = 0; i < integerImg.size(); i++) {
        if (i < 4) {

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);




            ImageView images = new ImageView(mContext);
            params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
            images.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsImage);
            images.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            images.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.salon_profile_back);
            images.setImageResource(integerImg.get(i));
            relativeLayout.addView(images);

            TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
            textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsImage);
            textView.setText("My Text");
            relativeLayout.addView(textView);

            linearImgGrid.addView(relativeLayout);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Shreyas Is it useful ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code for reference

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:weightSum="3"

            android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/user" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Master" />

 </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/report1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Report" />

 </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/expense1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Expenses" />

 </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:weightSum="2"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/collection" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Collection" />

 </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:weightSum="2"
             android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/monthly" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Report" />

 </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/extra" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Expenses" />

 </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant bits for the question, explain what you are posting outside the code block.